# AngularJS: Get specific object within a list from a watcher

Tags: angularjs

I am using a watcher to call a function whenever an array of objects is changed. What I want to know is if there is a way to pass in the particular object that has been modified.

For example, at the moment I could have -

```
$scope.$watch('Properties.Options', function (Value) {
...
}, true);
```

The content of Value would just hold my entire array of properties.options which is being watched. I'd like here to only pass in the object which has caused the watcher to become activated. I can figure out other ways by looping through the list, but I feel like I'm missing something and that that is probably unnecessary.

Comment: That's how you do it, you aren't missing anything.

Comment: Additional comment, $watch returns (newvalue, oldvalue), you can do the diff on those inside the function.